# Hiding extra imports from a package

Tags: python, pip, package, pypi

I have a package which allows importing much noise. I have tried to use the `__all__` like:

```
__all__ = ["WebdriverChauffeurMixin", "ChromeDriver", "FirefoxDriver"]
```

but this is not helping:

```
cchilders:~/projects/webdriver_chauffeur (master) 
$ pip uninstall webdriver-chauffeur
Can't uninstall 'webdriver-chauffeur'. No files were found to uninstall.

cchilders:~/projects/webdriver_chauffeur (master) 
$ pip uninstall webdriver_chauffeur
Can't uninstall 'webdriver-chauffeur'. No files were found to uninstall.

In [2]: from webdriver_chauffeur import 
BeautifulSoup            Keys                     os
By                       Select                   random
ChromeDriver             TimeoutException         subprocess
EC                       WebDriverWait            time
FirefoxDriver            WebdriverChauffeurMixin  webdriver
```

The package is on pypi but also on my machine at `~/projects/webdriver_chauffeur`

Package is at https://github.com/codyc4321/webdriver_chauffeur

How can I hide these unnecessary imports?

Comment: This looks like an `ipython` issue, not an `__all__` issue. Per [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/issues/129), this behavior is [configurable](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/options/terminal.html) (though the option is deprecated).

Comment: care to answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an `ipython` issue, not an `__all__` issue. Per this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/issues/129), this behavior is [configurable](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/options/terminal.html) (though the option is deprecated).